# DOMWindow dynamic popup dimension

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [DOMWindow example 3](http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html) for pop ups.
I have a list of images that vary in dimension and would like to have a window open to reflect those differences.
In order to capture each unique property I used `click` then assign some variable. The problem is that `click` is now registered 2x (meaning that i have to click twice), first from  `$(this).click(function ()` and also from `DOMWindow`'s `eventType:'click',`

**Question**: How can I fix this code so that variables can be captured then applied to `DOMWindow`'s method?

```
$(".fixedAjaxDOMWindow").each(function () {

    $(this).click(function () {

        var c = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
        //alert(c);
        var imgH = $(this).find(...)

        // click is registered again here
         $(this).openDOMWindow({
         //placing any code here breaks such as: var h = $(this).height();
            eventType:'click',
            width:800,
            height:imgH,
            positionType:'centered',
            positionTop:50,
            positionLeft:50,
            windowSource:'iframe',
            windowPadding:0,
            border:0,
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

i seem to have got it working with this.
If anyone has a better idea please let me know.

```
$(".fixedAjaxDOMWindow").mouseenter(function () {

        var imgH = $(this).find('img')...//get img height

         $(this).openDOMWindow({
            eventType:'click',
            width:800,
            height:imgH,
            positionType:'centered',
            positionTop:50,
            positionLeft:50,
            windowSource:'iframe',
            windowPadding:0,
            border:0,
        });

        return false;
    });
```